# Rails additional configuration in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use additional route files in my app, so when I add

```
config.paths['config/routes'] = Dir[Rails.root.join('config/routes/*.rb')]
```

to my `config/application.rb` file everything is fine.

The problem occurs, when I try to place this code in my initializer:

`MyApp::Application.config.paths['config/routes'] = Dir[Rails.root.join('config/routes/*.rb')]`

I check it in the rails console - `MyApp::Application.config.paths` hold proper path, but it seems that files from `config/routes` won't load.

How can I resolve this problem?

I'm using Rails 3.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not answering your question directly, but providing a different (better?) approach to what you're trying to do:*

Check out **[this alternative](https://gist.github.com/2492118)** that [DHH](https://gist.github.com/dhh) posted in a gist.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing approach :) And it could be solution for my problem. Thanks :)